# set difference as intersection, in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ two bounded open set such that
$A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.
In the following, I will denote as $\overline{A}$ as the closure of $A$.

Does the following equality holds true ?

$$A-\overline{B}=\overline{\left(A\cap B \right)}^{c}\cap A$$

The first inclusion ($\subset$) seems to be simple since:

$$
\overline{A\cap B}\subset\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}
$$

thus:
$$
\left(\overline{A}^{c}\cup\overline{B}^{c}\right)\cap A\subset\overline{A\cap B}^{c}\cap A
$$

therefore:
$$A-\overline{B}\subset\overline{\left(A\cap B \right)}^{c}\cap A$$

Nevertheless I have trouble with the second one.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Question on the second one - would A,A exist in U such that P(x) and P(x) when Q(x) not P(x)? Not A\B doesn't need to be declared because you are not evaluating the full Universe rather the function of that Universe in current form. For instance A,A is not necessarily a subset of A,B or B,A. To evaluate that you can use sentential logic

Comment: Hint: $(\overline{A\cap B})^c$ and $A$ are open sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X := (\overline{A\cap B})^c\cap A$ is the intersection of two open sets, hence it is open. Furthermore
\begin{equation}
X\cap B = (\overline{A\cap B})^c\cap (A\cap B)\subset
(\overline{A\cap B})^c\cap (\overline{A\cap B}) = \emptyset
\end{equation}
Hence the closed set $X^c$ contains $B$, hence it contains $\overline{B}$. Hence $X \subset (\overline{B})^c$, hence
\begin{equation}
X\subset A \setminus \overline{B}
\end{equation}

Comment: X sub A\B isn't the same as X sub B\A. Common oversight. A and (B or C). There's no proof here

Comment: @Barb Sorry I don't understand your point. Could you explain the details of where I'm wrong?

Comment: Sure thing. You declare that sub A and B are bounded by their intersection. The free variables are then bound. It's the same as just saying (A and B) and (A and B), which is just another way of saying A and B. Removing the set list across B from A is meaningless with this logic because they are all bound where the Universe X is left to be the free variable. X = B\A is not equal to X = A\B.

Comment: Essentially it requires a few more steps to fully prove, otherwise your just making a statement. Statements arent proof, rather examples of returning true or false

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice prove. So the bounded part can be drop.